# Insert Page Break after every 10 rows in iTextsharp table

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, page-break

I have table that could be over 3 pages long. But I only want 10 rows to be on each page. Is it possible to add a page break after every ten rows? I've tried adding a count and for every 10 rows insert the page break but the page break just goes to the top of the table, so the table starts on the second page.

```
        DataSet dsTable = null;
        dsTable = DataUtils.GetTableProperties(CompNew.CompanyID, "InvoicePrint");

        iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dsTable.Tables[1].Rows.Count);
        table.WidthPercentage = 100;

            int count = 0;
            foreach (DataRow record in records.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                foreach (string Heading in Headings)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Paragraph(record[Heading].ToString(), arialBold));
                }
                if (count != 0)
                {
                    if ((count % 10) == 0)
                    {
                        document.NewPage();
                    }
                }
                count++;

            }

    paragraphTable1.Add(table);
    document.Add(paragraphTable1);
```

Comment: I think the best answer would be: don't worry about the number of rows on the page, just make sure that rows aren't split. It's not clear *why* you only want to have 10 rows on every page. The reason you give us sounds like it's a bad workaround for a problem that might have a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
      if ((count % 10) == 0)
      {
         paragraphTable1.Add(table);
         document.Add(paragraphTable1);
         document.NewPage();
      }
```

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? I don't understand how and why this would work. (And I'm the guy who originally developed iText, so... I should understand, but I don't.)

Answer (score 0):

***table.DeleteBodyRows();*** is necessary to be executed before new page.

Try this:

```
  if ((count % 10) == 0)
  {
     paragraphTable1.Add(table);
     document.Add(paragraphTable1);
     table.DeleteBodyRows();
     document.NewPage();
  }
```

or in current version3.3.5 by iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core

```
  if ((count % 10) == 0)
  {
     document.Add(table);
     table.DeleteBodyRows();
     document.NewPage();
  }
```